# Django Rest Framework,Filtering objects based on Forignkey relationship

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a simple Blog app where anyone can add  post and *comment to post*.
Comments have forignkey relationship with Post.
When I select url patch `posts/<post id>/comments` it shows all comments instead of the comments from related posts. All other CRUD functions works fine with the project.

The Git Link :https://github.com/Anoop-George/DjangoBlog.git

The problem occurs in view.py where comment object unable to filter comments which are related to specific posts.

```
class CommentListCreate(APIView):
    def get(self, request,pk):
        **comment = Comment.objects.filter()** # I need filter here
        serializer = CommentSerializers(comment, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't use space in url `argument` or in general in urls. Url patch should be `posts/<int:post_id>/comments`.

Now, your class view looks like:

```
class CommentListCreate(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        id = kwargs.get("post_id", None)
        comment = Comment.objects.filter(post__id=id)
        serializer = CommentSerializers(comment, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I didn't get a chance to verify it but I am pretty sure it will work.

Comment: it works when I added pk with request,  def get(self, request,pk):
        
        comment = Comment.objects.filter(post__id=pk)
        serializer = CommentSerializers(comment, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)